# Integral Of $\int \frac{y}{e^{3y^2}}dy$

Tags: integration

I want to integrate the following :

$$\int \frac{y}{e^{3y^2}}dy$$
what I did so far is:
set $t=e^{3y^2}$ and $dt=6y\cdot e^{3y^2}dy$ from here I get get the expression:
$\frac{dt}{t}=6ydy$, there is another way to do it? any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Clean your substitution glasses: the given integral is $-\dfrac{1}{6}\int -6y\cdot e^{-3y^2}\,dy$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ I = \int ye^{-3y^2} \ dy $$

put $ -3y^2 = u \Rightarrow du = -6y dy $

$$ \Rightarrow I = -\frac{1}{6}\int e^u \ du = \frac{-e^u}{6} + c $$